# Angulajs use or inject services in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am new to use angularjs. I have create a directives and service within a seprate files. When i including a service into directive there is a Error: [$injector:modulerr].

Here is my file structure and files :-

Directive :- video_course.js

```
videoCourseApp.directive('mcssForm' ,function(){
        return{
            restrict : 'C',
            templateUrl : 'assets/template_blocks/mcss_form.html',
            link: function(scope,element,attribute){
            }
        };
});

videoCourseApp.directive('addNewMsccOption', function(incrementId){
        return{
            replace: true,
            restrict : 'C',
            template : '<li><input name="test" type="radio" ng-model="videoCourseQuestions.mcss_option"/><input ng-model="videoCourseOptions.Option{{newid}}" type="text"   class="option"  placeholder = "Enter your Option{{newid}}" />',
            link: function(scope,element,attribute){
                scope.newid = incrementId.getAndIncrement;
            }
        };
    });
```

And here is my service file :- videoservice.js

```
videoCourseApp.service('incrementId', function(){
    var index = 4;
    this.getAndIncrement = function () {
        return index++;
    };
});
```

And at finally here is my main app.js file where all methods are defined :-

```
var videoCourseApp = angular.module('videocourse' , ['ngDragDrop','mcssForm','addNewMsccOption']);

videoCourseApp.controller('video_course_add_question',function($scope, $timeout, $compile){


});
```

Here is my index.html file:->

```
<script src="assets/js/video_course/app.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/directives/video_course.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/services/video_services.js"></script>
```

This will give error of injector module. Where is the problem and how can i manage these dependencies in proper way.

Comment: Did you included videoservice.js` in you index.html

Comment: Yes i included there :- @PankajParkar

Comment: What is exactly the error that you get?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=videocourse&p1=Err…p%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fvideo_course%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A9)  @Omar.Alani

Comment: clcik on the link the error creates will explain itself to you...or use development version for verbose error and stack trace output

Comment: also doesn't make sense passing newId function to view expresssions ... try invoking function in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is wity the way you define your module. You are adding the directives as dependencies to the module videoCourseApp when all these directives are already in the same module. Only modules defined with module word can be injected as dependencies for the module. So try to remove these directives from the module defension.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look more like:

```
var videoCourseApp = angular.module('videocourse' , ['ngDragDrop']);

videoCourseApp.controller('video_course_add_question', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$compile', function($scope, $timeout, $compile){


}]);

videoCourseApp.service('incrementId', function(){
        var index = 4;
        this.getAndIncrement = function () {
        return index++;
    };
});

videoCourseApp.directive('addNewMsccOption', ['incrementId', function(incrementId){
    return{
        replace: true,
        restrict : 'C',
        template : '<li><input name="test" type="radio" ng-model="videoCourseQuestions.mcss_option"/><input ng-model="videoCourseOptions.Option{{newid}}" type="text"   class="option"  placeholder = "Enter your Option{{newid}}" />',
        link: function(scope,element,attribute){
            scope.newid = incrementId.getAndIncrement;
        }
    };
}]);

videoCourseApp.directive('mcssForm' ,function(){
    return{
        restrict : 'C',
        templateUrl : 'assets/template_blocks/mcss_form.html',
        link: function(scope,element,attribute){
        }
    };
});
```

Note the set up for dependency injection and minification in the controller and directive definitions.